# take id from select if not available in input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There is a small functionality, now when you click on a field, the input id of this field will be displayed.

But I also added another third field here, via dropDownList on yii2.

And the problem is that the id here is not in the input, but in the select.

How can I fix the javascript so that if there is undefined id in the input, then the id is taken from the select?

```js
$('.form-group input').each(function() {
    let input = $(this);
    $(this).closest('.range').find('.it').each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function () {
           console.log(input.attr('id'));
        })
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="range">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="field1" id="field1" value="">
  </div>
  <span class="it" data-value="1">click</span>
  <span class="it" data-value="2">click</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="range">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="field2" id="field2" value="">
  </div>
  <span class="it" data-value="1">click</span>
  <span class="it" data-value="2">click</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="range">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="field3" value="" disabled="">
    <select id="field3" class="d-none" name="field3[]" disabled="" multiple="" size="4" style="display: none">
      <option value="1">$0-20</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <span class="it" data-value="1">click</span>
  <span class="it" data-value="2">click</span>
</div>
```

Comment: update your selector to include a select. `$('.form-group input, .form-group select')`?

Comment: @epascarello then output 2 values, one from the input, the other from the select, I only need one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the select element from the `range` container when the input has no id:

```js
$('.form-group input').each(function() {
    let input = $(this);
    const range = $(this).closest('.range');
    range.find('.it').click(function(e){
      console.log(input.attr('id') || range.find('select').attr('id'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="range">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="field1" id="field1" value="">
  </div>
  <span class="it" data-value="1">click</span>
  <span class="it" data-value="2">click</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="range">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="field2" id="field2" value="">
  </div>
  <span class="it" data-value="1">click</span>
  <span class="it" data-value="2">click</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="range">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="field3" value="" disabled="">
    <select id="field3" class="d-none" name="field3[]" disabled="" multiple="" size="4" style="display: none">
      <option value="1">$0-20</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <span class="it" data-value="1">click</span>
  <span class="it" data-value="2">click</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you can check to see if an input

```js
$('.form-group input, .form-group select').each(function() {
    let input = $(this);
    // if the input has a select as an input, ignore it
    if (input.siblings('select').length) return;
    $(this).closest('.range').find('.it').each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function () {
           console.log(input.attr('id'));
        })
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="range">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="field1" id="field1" value="">
  </div>
  <span class="it" data-value="1">click</span>
  <span class="it" data-value="2">click</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="range">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="field2" id="field2" value="">
  </div>
  <span class="it" data-value="1">click</span>
  <span class="it" data-value="2">click</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="range">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="field3" value="" disabled="">
    <select id="field3" class="d-none" name="field3[]" disabled="" multiple="" size="4" style="display: none">
      <option value="1">$0-20</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <span class="it" data-value="1">click</span>
  <span class="it" data-value="2">click</span>
</div>
```

Or you can only select inputs with an id

```js
$('.form-group input[id], .form-group select[id]').each(function() {
    let input = $(this);
    if (input.siblings('select').length) return;
    $(this).closest('.range').find('.it').each(function() {
        $(this).on('click', function () {
           console.log(input.attr('id'));
        })
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="range">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="field1" id="field1" value="">
  </div>
  <span class="it" data-value="1">click</span>
  <span class="it" data-value="2">click</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="range">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="field2" id="field2" value="">
  </div>
  <span class="it" data-value="1">click</span>
  <span class="it" data-value="2">click</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="range">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="field3" value="" disabled="">
    <select id="field3" class="d-none" name="field3[]" disabled="" multiple="" size="4" style="display: none">
      <option value="1">$0-20</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <span class="it" data-value="1">click</span>
  <span class="it" data-value="2">click</span>
</div>
```